Are demonyms capitalized?
In Spanish and Portuguese, demonyms (American/americano) are not normally capitalized.  Same for names of languages (español/portuguese).  I thought it was that way for Italian, but is it?  The reason I asked is I just encountered a chapter of the bible that did it both ways.  It had both "Uria l’Itita" and "Uria l’itita" (Uriah the Hittite).

What you are asking is explained in the section I.194.h).II) of the book Italiano by Luca Serianni this way:

in riferimento agli abitanti, è oggi più comune la minuscola, che diventa usuale al singolare e obbligatoria con gli aggettivi: quindi gli Italiani o gli italiani, ma prevalentemente l'italiano e soltanto i prodotti italiani. La maiuscola può tornare utile, nei sostantivi, per dissipare equivoci: i Romani antichi / i romani moderni, i Galli della Gallia / i galli del pollaio (cfr. SATTA 1981: 102); ed è in genere preferita per i nomi storici, anche in assenza di un omonimo: «in pochi anni i Longobardi furono padroni dell'interno dell'Italia settentrionale» (Spini, Disegno storico, I 64; invece, con un nome moderno: «gli uomini politici fautori di una politica di cautela e di amicizia con gli anglo-americani», ivi III 416).

Translated into English this would be:

with reference to inhabitants, it is now more common to use lowercase, which becomes usual in the singular and obligatory with adjectives: therefore gli Italiani or gli italiani, but predominantly l'italiano and only i prodotti italiani. Uppercase can be useful in nouns to clear up ambiguities: i Romani antichi / i romani moderni, i Galli della Gallia / i galli del pollaio (cf. SATTA 1981: 102); and it is generally preferred for historical names, even in the absence of a homonym: «in pochi anni i Longobardi furono padroni dell'interno dell'Italia settentrionale» (Spini, Disegno storico, I 64; instead, with a modern name: «gli uomini politici fautori di una politica di cautela e di amicizia con gli anglo-americani», ibid. III 416).

Being ittita referred to a historical Ancient people, uppercase it's preferred when used as a name, as you can see in this definition from the Grande dizionario della lingua italiana:

Studio storico e archeologico della civiltà degli Ittiti.

But, according to Serianni, lowercase is also accepted and it's compulsory when ittita is an adjective, as in these expressions coming from the vocabolario Treccani

la storia, la religione ittita; la lingua ittita [...] i poemi ittiti


So, would "Hittite" (itita) be considered a historical name?  (Either way, the 2006 text I saw was inconsistent by doing it both ways)

@WGroleau: I think so.

@WGroleau: In fact, in Italian it's ittita / Ittita.

(sheepish grin) I didn't even notice that the quote actually used the same name that prompted my question!
